# Ionic searchbar search not working on cypress {enter}

Tags: ionic-framework, cypress

I have an Ionic 6 app and I'm testing it with cypress 9.3.1.

In my app I'm using an ion-searchbar like this:

```
<ion-searchbar *ngIf="showSearchbar" [value]="search" (search)="searchQuestions($event)"
                     placeholder="{{'components.search.placeholder' | translate}}">
```

The searchQuestions method looks like this:

```
  public searchQuestions(event): void {
    console.log('test');
    this.triggerSearch.emit(event.target.value);
  }
```

When I test it manually everything works fine, but when I execute the cypress code like this:

```
cy.get('.searchbar-input')
    .type('test1' + '{leftArrow}{del}{enter}' + 'test');
```

the input field is filled with `testtest`, so the `{leftArrow}{del}` is working, but the `console.log` from `searchQuestions` is not executed and the event is not emitted

EDIT: When I use `(keyup.enter)="searchQuestions($event)"` instead of `(search)="searchQuestions($event)"` it seems to work fine. But I guess replacing it would be problematic for native apps and keeping both might cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app or the Ionic framework is adding an event handler to trigger the `search` event, but Cypress doesn't know about it.

In the `.type()` command it issues keyboard events only, which is why `(keyup.enter)="searchQuestions($event)"` fires but `(search)="searchQuestions($event)"` does not.

The first thing to try is

```js
cy.get('.searchbar-input')
  .type('test1' + '{leftArrow}{del}{enter}' + 'test')
  .trigger('search')
```

Also try triggering other events like `.trigger('change')` and `.trigger('input')`.

---

The other thing that might cause it is the `{enter}` in the middle of the typed string.

Try `.type('test1' + '{leftArrow}{del}' + 'test' + '{enter}')` - this seems more like the pattern a user would use.

Comment: trigger('search') does the trick! The `{enter}` in the middle was only for testing purposes to clarify my case. I deleted everything and it works well like this: 
`cy.get('.searchbar-input')
  .type('test')
  .trigger('search')`. Thanks a lot