# unable to trigger click on button in Ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cypress, shadow-dom

I can't seem to click the "CREATE ACCOUNT" ion-button as it is covered.
It either generates the error below or if I use {force: true} it passes but does nothing.
If I click manually on the screen, it works fine.
I have searched all the posts on this, but nothing seems to work.

I have tried using the following:

```
   cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click({force: true});
   cy.get('#btn-register-submit', {includeShadowDom: true}).trigger("click", {force: true});
   cy.get('#btn-register-submit').trigger('mouseover').click();
   cy.get('#btn-register-submit').trigger('mouseover', {force: true}).click({force: true});
   cy.get('#btn-register-submit', {includeShadowDom: true}).click({force: true});
   cy.get('#btn-back').click({force: true});
```

Interestingly if I use

```
cy.get('#btn-back').click({force: true});
```

This click works on the back button, even though it has the same error without the force.

**LATEST UPDATE**

I figured it out. Turns out I need to fill in both the ion-input and the shadow input.
Here is my code:

```
cy.visit('/login');
    cy.get('#btn-create-account').click()
    cy.get('.tenant-card').contains('NZ Speeder Club').first().click()
    cy.get('#select').click()
    cy.get('#btn-submit').should('exist')
    cy.get('input[name="input-email"]').eq(0).click({force: true}).type(`${name}${emailDomain}`, {force: true})
    cy.get('input[name="input-email"]').eq(1).click().type(`${name}${emailDomain}`)
    cy.get('input[name="input-first-name"]').eq(0).click({force: true}).type(`${name}`, {force: true})
    cy.get('input[name="input-first-name"]').eq(1).click().type(`${name}`)
    cy.get('input[name="input-last-name"]').eq(0).click({force: true}).type(`${name}`, {force: true})
    cy.get('input[name="input-last-name"]').eq(1).click().type(`${name}`)
    cy.get('input[name="input-password"]').eq(0).click({force: true}).type(password, {force: true})
    cy.get('input[name="input-password"]').eq(1).click().type(password)
    cy.get('input[name="passwordConfirm"]').eq(0).click({force: true}).type(password, {force: true})
    cy.get('input[name="passwordConfirm"]').eq(1).click().type(password)
    // cy.get('input[name="input-phone"]').eq(1).type('Phone') 
    cy.get('#btn-submit').click({force: true})
```

**UPDATE:**

It turns out that the click is actually working but the Angular form is not valid for some reason. I have tried adding .click().focus() to the input elements but no luck. It works normally so must be something to do with Cypress.

The rendered HTML:
[image]

[image]

My Cypress tests:

```
it('Create account', () => {
    const prefix = TodaysDatePrefix();
    const suffix = RandomAlphaSuffix();
    const name = prefix + suffix;
    const emailDomain = '@wekasolutions.co.nz'; 
    const password = 'wekaT3st'

    cy.visit('/login');
    cy.get('#btn-create-account').click()
    cy.get('.tenant-card').contains('NZ Speeder Club').first().click()
    cy.get('#select').click()
    // cy.get('#btn-register-submit').should('exist')
    cy.get('input[name="input-email"]').eq(1).click().focus()
    cy.get('input[name="input-email"]').eq(1).type(`${name}${emailDomain}`)
    cy.get('input[name="input-first-name"]').eq(0).click().focus()
    cy.get('input[name="input-first-name"]').eq(0).type(`${name}`)
    cy.get('input[name="input-last-name"]').eq(1).click().focus()
    cy.get('input[name="input-last-name"]').eq(1).type(`${name}`)
    // cy.get('input[name="input-phone"]').eq(1).type('Phone') 
    cy.get('input[name="input-password"]').eq(1).click().focus()
    cy.get('input[name="input-password"]').eq(1).type(password)
    cy.get('input[name="passwordConfirm"]').eq(1).click().focus()
    cy.get('input[name="passwordConfirm"]').eq(1).type(password)
    // cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click({force: true});
    // cy.get('#btn-register-submit', {includeShadowDom: true}).trigger("click", {force: true});
    // cy.get('#btn-register-submit').trigger('mouseover').click();
    // cy.get('#btn-register-submit').trigger('mouseover', {force: true}).click({force: true});
    // cy.get('#btn-register-submit', {includeShadowDom: true}).click({force: true});
    cy.get('#btn-test').click({force: true})
    cy.get('#btn-submit').click({force: true})
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `#btn-register-submit` is inside the shadow DOM, but you need to specify `{includeShadowDom: true}` before the `cy.get('#btn-register-submit')`.

The easiest way is to set it on the test header

```js
it('tests an ionic button inside shadowDOM`, {includeShadowDom: true}, () => {
  ...
```

or set it globally in `cypress.config.js`.

That way you don't have to worry about where the shadow roots are (in ionic they are everywhere).

Comment: Thanks I will actually add that. However it turns on the button was being clicked and the form was not valid for some reason. It works normally so it must be a Cypress thing, so I am still looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to fill in both the ion-input and the shadow input.
This is for an Ionic Angular app.

Its not an ideal solution as there is a lot of duplication so if anyone knows a better solution I will accept that.

Here is my code:

```
cy.visit('/login');
cy.get('#btn-create-account').click()
cy.get('.tenant-card').contains('NZ Speeder Club').first().click()
cy.get('#select').click()
cy.get('#btn-submit').should('exist')
cy.get('input[name="input-email"]').eq(0).click({force: true}).type(`${name}${emailDomain}`, {force: true})
cy.get('input[name="input-email"]').eq(1).click().type(`${name}${emailDomain}`)
cy.get('input[name="input-first-name"]').eq(0).click({force: true}).type(`${name}`, {force: true})
cy.get('input[name="input-first-name"]').eq(1).click().type(`${name}`)
cy.get('input[name="input-last-name"]').eq(0).click({force: true}).type(`${name}`, {force: true})
cy.get('input[name="input-last-name"]').eq(1).click().type(`${name}`)
cy.get('input[name="input-password"]').eq(0).click({force: true}).type(password, {force: true})
cy.get('input[name="input-password"]').eq(1).click().type(password)
cy.get('input[name="passwordConfirm"]').eq(0).click({force: true}).type(password, {force: true})
cy.get('input[name="passwordConfirm"]').eq(1).click().type(password)
cy.get('#btn-submit').click({force: true})
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you should be able to `.trigger('change')` or `.trigger('input')` after the `.type()`. The event should make the ionic element move the value inside the shadow.

Comment: See [Ionic searchbar search not working on cypress {enter}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71300285/16997707).